# How to generate random number in liquid shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid

If logic contains a date object please note that the value will be the current time of when the page was last generated from the template, not when the page is presented to a user if caching or static site generation is involved as per the Shopify article. It will return a similar number every time.

Comment: It is important to remember that Liquid is a templating language, not a programming language.  It is not designed for truly random number generation - it is designed to be cacheable for servers delivering the content. For true randomness, you will want to use a programming language like Javascript.

Comment: I am also looking for this feature, which appears to be problematic due to caching. For my case I want to create a href to a random article in my blog depending on the random number, for instance in a list between article 1 and article 30. I don't know how this is possible since I don't think javascript can interact with the liquid to serve a different link?

Comment: The answers below show correctly how to generate a random number in Liquid, but the results are chached as you mentioned.. Rather edit this question and ask a new question if you want to show a random post in Shopify for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the timestamp to get a large number and use math to get a random-looking result. Eg to get a random number between 0 and 100:

```
{% assign randomNumber = "now" | date: "%N" | modulo: 100 %}
```

*(remember that this will generate an integer anywhere from 0 to 99 inclusive.)*

Or a random number between 10 and 20:

```
{% assign min = 10 %}
{% assign max = 20 %}
{% assign diff = max | minus: min %}
{% assign randomNumber = "now" | date: "%N" | modulo: diff | plus: min %}
```

**NB:** Liquid files are cached so the random number is only generated on page creation and doesn't change every time you view the page. For that, you would need javascript.

Answer (score 4):

```
{% assign random_number = "now" | date: "%N" | modulo: 1000 | plus: 0 %}
```

Worked for me, provides a random number between 0 - 1000.

Comment: `| plus: min` does nothing in this case because you didn't define min

Comment: @TimoSolo forgot to include, I updated the answer.

Comment: Number is created upon each page refresh. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Use the code to generate a random number

```
{% capture random %}{{ 'now' | date: "%09N" }}{% endcapture %}
```

---

output it using

```
{{random}}
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to refresh a random number when I try it

Comment: @DevOverflow this is because the date object is being cached and does not return a dynamic value. This is a common Shopify problem.