# Shopify - Display random value on frontend from list of string values in metafield

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

I have created a metafield of "quotes" that holds a list of hardcoded string values in my shopify backend.

I have a text field on my Shopify frontend on a variety of different pages (home page, product pages, collection pages, etc.)

What I would like to do is have that text field display 1 random value pulled from the list of harcoded string values I stored in the metafield.

Is this possible? And if so, any advice on how to achieve would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: on the frontend, you use javascript to show randomly from string with ease. use liquid code to fetch all metafiles strings and create a JSON object. on page load simply show the random string from JSON string using javastring.

Comment: Here is a liquid approach, but due to the template side cache it doesn't seem to work 100% each time. [Link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65322642/how-to-generate-random-number-in-liquid-shopify)